# Using Android Studio on different computers

Tags: android-studio

I use Android Studio on my PC and my Laptop.  My projects are stored in Google Drive, but Google Drive is in different places on the PC and laptop.

I just edited a project on my laptop, now I try and run the emulator on my PC for this project and I get an error as it's looking for some things in the location they were on the laptop.

```
04/23 10:34:51: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r S:\Google Drive\AndroidProjects\Connect3\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk S:\Google Drive\AndroidProjects\Connect3\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk C:\Users\AndyC\Google Drive\AndroidProjects\Connect3\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk...
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.androidandyuk.connect3
Unknown failure (at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565))
Error while Installing APKs
```

The S drive is where they are on PC and C is on the laptop.

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Fix it by using a [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), not Google Drive and also get the other benefits of a VCS.

Comment: Thanks, but how will that fix my current issue?  Surely that lets me avoid the issue in the future?

Is there some kind of rebuild I can make it do?

Comment: It will allow you to place dependencies relative to your project when checking out on different devices - not on drive letter names and absolute paths that subject to change. Maybe look into some open source / sample projects on github and see how they are organized / structured.

Comment: Thanks, I've signed up and figured out GitHub, including adding it to Android Studio.  I don't suppose it's possible to automate a commit on shutting it down?

Comment: Not sure about Android Studio but there's an example for [automatic push on Windows Shutdown](https://blog.kulman.sk/automatically-push-your-git-repos-before-computer-shutdown/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I thought adding in Github would only help me going forward, it must reformat the code to work independent of your own file system as I was able to edit it again.